# Solve: Merging two branches of the solution

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code:

```
sols = x /. 
     Solve[1/4 (x^4 + 3^4) + (9/2 + 0.5^2 - 1) x^2 + 2 x (a - 10 \[ImaginaryI]) + 
          9*0.5^2 - (a - 10 \[ImaginaryI])^2 == 0, x];
```

Then I want to plot the real part of two of the solutions:

```
Plot[{Re[sols[[1]]], Re[sols[[4]]]}, {a, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

This gives me

[image]

My question is: Can I make *Mathematica* to give me continuous solutions, so that in my example `sols[[1]]` represents the upper branch and `sols[[2]]` is the lower branch?

Comment: Before going any further try setting `Exclusions -> False` and see what's going on and why you have those discontinuous solutions.

Comment: Exclusions->False, Exclusions->None and Exclusions->True does not make any difference...

Comment: Are you sure ?! Because when I use `Exclusions -> False` get the following plot http://i.stack.imgur.com/DMSpR.png

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun: in the following the complex plane (reflected through the line of identity) is plotted with variation in parameter `a`. The red points show behviour of roots with `a` and the colored lines are the desired plots using the horizontal axis as `a` (as well as the Imaginary axis):

```
sol[a_] := 
  x /. NSolve[
    1/4 (x^4 + 3^4) + (9/2 + 0.5^2 - 1) x^2 + 2 x (a - 10 I) + 
      9*0.5^2 - (a - 10 I)^2 == 0, x];
f[w_] := Transpose[Through[{Im, Re}[sol[w]]]]
Manipulate[Show[Plot[{Re[sol[w]][[1]],
    Re[sol[w]][[2]], Re[sol[w][[3]]], Re[sol[w]][[4]]}, {w, -10, 10}, 
   Exclusions -> None, Epilog -> {Point[{q, #} & /@ Re[sol[q]]]}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a/Im", "Re"}], 
  ListPlot[f[q], PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Graphics[{Line[Thread[{f[q], {q, #} & /@ Re[sol[q]]}]], 
    EdgeForm[Orange], FaceForm[None], 
    Polygon[f[q][[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]]}]], {q, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fixing the 0.5, which was asking for trouble (don't feed approximate numbers to exact machinery), and then telling it Quartics->False

`sols = x /.
   Solve[1/4 (x^4 + 3^4) + (9/2 + (1/2)^2 - 1) x^2 + 2 x (a - 10 I) + 
      9*(1/2)^2 - (a - 10 I)^2 == 0, x, Quartics -> False]`

`{Root[490 + 80 I a - 4 a^2 - 80 I #1 + 8 a #1 + 15 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 1], 
 Root[490 + 80 I a - 4 a^2 - 80 I #1 + 8 a #1 + 15 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2], 
 Root[490 + 80 I a - 4 a^2 - 80 I #1 + 8 a #1 + 15 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3], 
 Root[490 + 80 I a - 4 a^2 - 80 I #1 + 8 a #1 + 15 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4]}`

It might seem like Mathematica didn't really do anything, but actually those are perfectly good, perfectly precise solutions. Furthermore, they are ordered in a convenient way for you: using Root[],real solutions come before complex solutions, and the groups are ordered by their real parts. It looks like they're all complex, and the two you're looking for are the middle ones:

```
Plot[Re[{sols[[2]], sols[[3]]}], {a, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Plot]

Added edit:

Not enough coffee yet this morning. I didn't notice that the plot didn't have colors. To get coloring, the function list must be an explicit list when Plot first looks at it. And plotting all four solutions is also illuminating, so:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[sols]], {a, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Color Plot]
Note that the ordering causes the curves to "bounce" where they touch.

Comment: Thanks, but I have Mathematica 6.0 and there the option "Quartics" does not seem to be there. Is there another way to achieve your result. And can I suppress the bouncing?

Comment: 6.0? Ancient history ;-). I don't think Mathematica had root isolation back then, so you're in the land of radicals. That makes it harder.

Comment: In general, there is no way of ordering the roots that is good for every purpose. The root isolation methods behind Root[] tend to order solutions better for my purposes than radical-based solutions. Radicals tend to lead to rather unpredictable behavior, while Root[] has a well-defined ordering (at least in recent Mathematica versions). But there is no general mathematical answer to the difficulty of ordering roots for particular problems. You have to write a function that orders the roots according to some problem-specific criterion. There's no magic wand you can wave to banish the bounces.

Comment: Ok, but anyway, the option "Quartics" does not exactly do what I want, it sorts the solutions by their real part, but I want to have continuous solutions, no jumps and no bouncing. So if two solutions are crossing zero I want to stay on one branch and not always on the positive one. With the quartics option there would be a bounce like in your graph.

Comment: Hm, is there really no option for mathematica to choose the branches in a way that you get smooth and continuous solutions? I mean if you look at your graph you immediately see that the bouncing is weird and that it would be more convenient without any bouncing

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to order the solutions of a polynomial such that there is no point of view from which the ordering is "weird". Consider the following:

```
p = (s^2 + wA^2) (s^2 + wB^2) + k s
```

(those used to analyzing linear circuits will see two independent resonators at angular frequencies `wA` and `wB`, with common feedback determined by `k`).

Assume that `wA` is 100, `k` is 0 (so the resonators are truly independent):

```
r = s /. Solve[{p == 0}, {s}, Quartics -> False] /. wA -> 100;
r0 = r /. k -> 0;
```

Now plot the the imaginary parts of roots two and four as we vary `wB`.

```
Plot[{Im[r0[[2]]], Im[r0[[4]]]}, {wB, 0, 200}]
```

[image: No Feedback]
"Weird", right? We expect the frequencies to track `wA` and `wB`, and they kind of do, but the blue curve tracks `wB` at low frequencies and `wA` at high frequencies. The curves "bounce" where `wA==wB`.

But now, add a little feedback and zoom in:

```
r1 = r /. k -> 1;
Plot[{Im[r1[[2]]], Im[r1[[4]]]}, {wB, 99, 101}]
```

[image: Feedback, zoom]

In fact, the curves don't touch if `k` isn't exactly zero: they really do "repel" each other and "bounce". So, from this point of view it would be "weird" to associate the branches with `wA` and `wB`: they don't connect continuously that way.

So, in the case of `k==0`, is it "wierder" to have different branches from the `k!=0` case, or "weirder" to have them switch resonators at the degeneracy? Mathematics has no answer. To even discuss the issue, you need to go outside of pure mathematics and speak in terms of your application. But even then, Mathematica has no general machinery to define what answer you might prefer (and I can't imagine how it might work).

Comment: Well, this makes sense, I understand what you mean.

Comment: Actually my problem was that Mathematica said there is a zero crossing in the solutions plotted in my first post. Is there a way to tell Mathematica not to accept such zero crossings (Exclusions->True does not work).