# Solution Branch Switching of Quartic

Tags: equation-solving

Im using a closed form solution for quartic equation. In the quartic equation, there are parameters that are being varied and therefore the solution changes depending on these parameters.

The solution of the individual branches are not smooth and not continuous.
The smooth curve can be obtained if two branches are used

[image: The figure shows the two branches].

At the switching point, the discriminant is positive (so there are no multiple roots).

How can I obtain a smooth solution in a single branch, or is there any way to switch the branches (without using `Piecewise`)?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84428/solve-merging-two-branches-of-the-solution)?

Comment: Any reason not to use `Root[]` objects?

Comment: Please post your quartic equation with its parameters.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Lichtblau. The link was useful.